# Riverpod create provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod

I want to create provider that will return String with Riverpod. I'm using Provider as below. I'm getting an error `The instance member 'name' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression`. May someone tell me how should I create provider?

```
class LearnUser {
  final String uid;

  final String name;
  final usernameProvider = Provider((ref) {
    return name;
  });
  LearnUser({required this.uid});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would separate the provider from the LearnUser class. It gives cleaner separation of concerns in my opinion. And what i understood from the Riverpod docs they are ment as global vars. Like the above poster mentioned your code won't work cause you are trying to access an instance variable.

Maybe something like this with a user service. I would also advice you look into `StateNotifier` with `StateNotifierProvider` you could use for example to create a user service.

```dart
// Creating the provider as global variable
final userNameProvider = Provider<String>((ref) => 
  ref.watch(userService.state)?.user.name ?? '';
);
```

Comment: An alternative is creating the provider as a static member of the class. I find this is helpful for organization purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
@riverpod
class UserName extends _$UserName{
  @override
  String build() =>  '';

  String getName() => state;
  void setName(String name) { state = name ; }
}

class LearnUser {
  final String uid;

  final String name;
  LearnUser({required this.uid,required this.name});
}

final learnUser = LearnUser(uid: '....',name: ref.watch(userNameProvider) );
```

This last line of code should be used in:

1. consumer widget
2. consumer stateful widget
3. other providers

Answer (score -1):

'name' is instance member. You need an instance to access a member variable.
You can try this

```
class LearnUser {
 final String uid;
 String name;
 Provider usernameProvider;
 LearnUser({@required this.uid}){
  this.usernameProvider = Provider((ref) {
   return this.name;
  });
 }
}
```